# How to split single row CSV?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, string-manipulation

I have a CSV file that imports like this:

Field1_Entry1,Field2_Entry1,...FieldN_Entry1,Field1_Entry2,Field2_Entry2...

I intend to have a new row after Field N so I get a table with N columns:

Field1_Entry1 | Field2_Entry1 | ...FieldN_Entry1

Field1_Entry2 | Field2_Entry2 | ...FieldN_Entry2

etc

Fwiw I have been able to insert a blank column after each FieldN using a delimiter but I haven't figured out how to jump to a new row.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I am assuming that the "..." is not inside the file? but it is seperated with a comma?

Comment: yes indeed, my bad, all values are separated in commas, I just new a new row after every N columns

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you still want each cell to contain Field*x*_Entry*x*, right?  If so, it's just  simple matter of converting all of the commas to tabs.  Open the file in a text editor and do a global search and replace.  Then select all, copy, and paste into Excel.  This assumes you don't have any commas in your actual field names or data.

I just noticed your edit... you'll also need to replace ",Field1" with "{CRLF}Field1"

Comment: right, this is my current workaround. I was wondering if there is one within excel..

Comment: Well you could probably write a VB Script that could parse the file, but I think that's only worthwhile if you have multiple files that need the same treatment.

Comment: You can do this in Excel using [Text to Columns](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html).